# No response from google cloud speech

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-speech

I'm trying to use Google cloud speech api. I found a weird behaviour that occured several times. I don't understand why, i can't get any response from google cloud speech.

Here is the code :

```
 public String ConvertSpeech(File audioFile) {
      SpeechClient speech = null;
    try {
        speech = SpeechClient.create();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      Path path = Paths.get(audioFile.getName());
      byte[] data = null;
    try {
        data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      ByteString audioBytes = ByteString.copyFrom(data);
      // Configure request with local raw PCM audio
      RecognitionConfig config = RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
          .setEncoding(AudioEncoding.LINEAR16)
          .setLanguageCode("fr-FR")
          .setSampleRateHertz(16000)
          .build();
      RecognitionAudio audio = RecognitionAudio.newBuilder()
          .setContent(audioBytes)
          .build();
      // Use blocking call to get audio transcript
    //  RecognizeResponse response = speech.recognize(config, audio);
        OperationFuture<LongRunningRecognizeResponse, LongRunningRecognizeMetadata> response =
                speech.longRunningRecognizeAsync(config, audio);

        while (!response.isDone()) {
            System.out.println("Waiting for response...");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
        List<SpeechRecognitionResult> results = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            results = response.get().getResultsList();
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    //  List<SpeechRecognitionResult> results = response.getResultsList();
        // There can be several alternative transcripts for a given chunk of speech. Just use the
        // first (most likely) one here.
      if(results.size()!=0){
          SpeechRecognitionAlternative alternative = results.get(0).getAlternativesList().get(0);
           // System.out.printf("Transcription: %s%n", alternative.getTranscript());
            try {
                speech.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return alternative.getTranscript(); 
      }
       // System.out.printf("Transcription: %s%n", alternative.getTranscript());
        try {
            speech.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";

    }
```

When i run that, everything is ok but sometimes, google stop answering for the rest of the day. Then, everything is ok the tomorow morning. It is not something like api limitation because i only used it only a few time (around 4 times 5 sec) before the bug occured.

First i thought it was because of a format that was wrong, but i store all the sound files as .wav the same way, so there is no reason some bug and others not.

For instance today, 5 requests have been send, the 6th, the 7th and the 8th bugged and on the google cloud console I can't find anything about those failed request. It looks like those requests vanished between

```
OperationFuture<LongRunningRecognizeResponse, LongRunningRecognizeMetadata> 
    response = speech.longRunningRecognizeAsync(config, audio);
```

and google cloud speech.

Here is the console output :

```
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
Waiting for response...
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.api.gax.rpc.DeadlineExceededException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: deadline exceeded after 599979147331ns
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:500)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:459)
at com.google.api.gax.longrunning.OperationFutureImpl.get(OperationFutureImpl.java:106)
at mypackage.GoogleCloudSpeechService.ConvertSpeech(GoogleCloudSpeechService.java:66)
```